# Visual Studio Code on Azure ARM template reports unable to load schema - unexpected end of file

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-resource-manager

Using an ARM template, taken from a Microsoft example, I have this:

```
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
```

which results in this:

```
Unable to load schema from 'http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json': unexpected end of file.
```

When I manually retrieve the schema file, it returns this:

```
{"id":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#","$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#","title":"Parameters","description":"An Azure deployment parameter file","type":"object","properties":{"$schema":{"type":"string"},"contentVersion":{"type":"string","pattern":"(^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$)","description":"A 4 number format for the version number of this parameter file. For example, 1.0.0.0"},"parameters":{"type":"object","additionalProperties":{"$ref":"#/definitions/parameter"},"description":"Collection of parameters to pass into a template"}},"additionalProperties":false,"required":["$schema","contentVersion","parameters"],"definitions":{"parameter":{"type":"object","properties":{"value":{"$ref":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#/definitions/parameterValueTypes","description":"Input value to template"},"reference":{"$ref":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#/definitions/keyVaultReference","description":"KeyVault parameter reference"},"metadata":{"type":"object","description":"Client specific metadata"}},"additionalProperties":false,"oneOf":[{"required":["value"]},{"required":["reference"]}]}}}
```

The above passes several types of json validation including jsonlint, so I don't see why VSCode is complaining about it.

Anybody solve this problem?

Comment: I've got the same error but for the parameters file, not the main template (also I'm not using `-preview`). Important to note that the template and parameter files reference different schemas (`deploymentTemplate.json` vs `deploymentParameters.json`). I've raised an issue over on the extension [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurearmtools/issues/1441).

Answer (score 1):

As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#template-format), use the latest version of `$schema`

> If you're using Visual Studio Code with the Azure Resource Manager tools extension, use the latest version for resource group deployments:
> https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#

Use this version `2019-04-01` instead of `2014-04-01-preview`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a more updated schema like:

https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json

using:

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
```